# Landscape forces premature pagebreak

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, page-breaking, landscape

After some trouble I have managed to make a table in landscape orientation that breaks over three pages. I used `tabularx` and the `landscape` package. Now my problem is that the thing won't float like normal but instead breaks the text where it is, causing a premature page break. I have tried using `sidewaystable` and `hvfloat` but can't get it to work (are they incompatible with `tabularx`? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't need to sign with your name, as it will automatically appear in the lower right corner of your post. Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Also you may want to try the `longtable` package.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand correctly the description of the problem, you (i) have some material of the form

```
% lots of material
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{...}
% content of longtable
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
% lots more material
```

and (ii) don't want (pdf)LaTeX to create a page break *immediately* upon encountering the `\begin{landscape}` instruction. Instead, you want LaTeX to defer switching to landscape mode until the current page is filled up by typesetting some of the "lots more material" group.

If this interpretation is correct, you may want to take a look at the instruction `\afterpage`. All you would need to do is to load the `afterpage` package (in the preamble) and encase the entire `landscape` group (which, in this case, contains a `longtable` environment) in an `\afterpage{...}` instruction. As the instruction's name suggests, LaTeX defers the typesetting of the material in its argument until the current page comes to an end by some other means (most likely because some additional material is being typeset, causing a natural page break at some point).

Note that it is *very important* to remember to use a right curly brace, `}`, to mark the end of the material that forms the argument of the `\afterpage` instruction. (If you forget the `}`, LaTeX will keep running until it encounters `\end{document}` and then issue one of its cryptic error messages.) In an answer to a related question that was posted recently, David Carlisle has suggested doing the following to simplify the process of making sure not to forget the closing curly brace: Place the entire landscape-longtable material in a separate file, say `landlong.tex`, and then issue the instruction

```
\afterpage{\input landlong}
```

in the main file. That way, one is almost surely not going to forget that pesky right curly brace, right?